# gitlab not working after installing nagios and apache but still both nginx and gitlab are running

Tags: apache, nginx, gitlab, nagios

I installed nagios and apache using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-4-and-monitor-your-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04

OS: Ubuntu

But after that, gitlab(using nginx) that is already installed in my server stopped working. But another website that is using the same nginx is working.

Stopped means, nginx and gitlab processes are running(I guess) but site is not opening, saying "502 Bad Gateway".

Note that I stopped services nagios and apache2 but still.

Comment: A separate install of nginx comes with gitlab that it uses. You created a conflict between the two by installing the system nginx on top of it.

Comment: I got solution, fyi :)